# This action will cancel a pending refresh data command

Tags: excel, vba

While I am trying this code I am getting the error "This action will cancel a pending refresh data command.continue?"

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Even if I put `Application.Wait now() + TimeValue("00:01:20")` Excel is not refreshing properly.

Comment: Hello there! By any chance, do you have background queries in your file? Perhaps a connection to Access or the like?

Comment: You maybe need to provide a bit more context to your question.

Comment: i have one software its called JDE.while i am refreshing excel it wil fetch the data from that software.and i have only refreshall button in the sheet

Answer (score 21):

Solution:
"Go to the data tab, click connections in the connections group, click on EVERY connection and click properties, un-check the box that says "enable background refresh"." (tylerlohman@gmail.com , pcreview, 2013).

This error may be caused by Excel being overloaded but only capable of reporting in this way. After trying all of the suggestions about 'DoEvents', 'WAIT'/SLEEP', 'FOR/NEXT' looping and opening each page to refresh singularly, I found, from PCReview website, that the solution is in the Data Connection properties and not VBA.

Once all background refresh connections have been disabled, the simple 'Activeworkbook.RefreshAll' command will suffice to update the entire workbook; mine was 29 pages large with 5 data connections and 7 SQL data connections.

NB: It was only the SQL data connections which allow the refresh to be disabled.

Hope that this helps with anyone having a headache over this issue as I did.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to solve my issue...
I had build a huge automation process, as a part of it is to pull ad group users based on sql data. Excel vba trowed the error "this action will cancel pending refresh..."
After i changed the background refresh option it work fine... :)
thanks again...