# How to auto "OK" or bypass pop up message in Excel with win32com in Python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, win32com

I'm attempting to change the file types of a large group of .xls files to .xlsm, and keep getting pop up messages that I have to "OK" or "YES" out of before the script proceeds.

I've already attempted the time.sleep SendKeys method, and the "ENTER" command does not register in the window created by Excel.

I've also attempted DisplayAlerts = False, but no luck with that either. Below is the code I've used with the comment lines being what I attempted:

```
os.chdir(r'C:\my\directory\location')
doc_path = r'C:\my\directory\location'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(doc_path, topdown=False):
    for file in files:

        fname = file

        if fname.endswith('.xls'):
            excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
            #excel.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(fname))
            #time.sleep(4)
            #excel.SendKeys("~",0)
            #excel.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb.SaveAs(fname+"m", FileFormat = 52) 
            #excel.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb.Close()                      
            #excel.DisplayAlerts = False
            excel.Application.Quit()        
            #excel.DisplayAlerts = False

        else:
            continue
```

Any insight on how I might be able to solve this?

Comment: you can probably use something like `pynput` to send mouse clicks or enter keys (you might have to send TAB first until "OK" is highlighted)

Comment: as an aside python may just not be the best tool for the job in this one case... here is some xlsm workbook that seems to do exactly what you want https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/8269/Convert-between-Excel-file-formats-XLS-XLSX-XLSM-with-without-macro-option.html

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, it's not with your code, but how you have set up your data connections in excel. What you need to do is disable background refreshes.

1. Got to excel and navigate to the "Data" tab
2. Click on "Queries & Connections"
3. For each of your queries, right click and open "Properties"
4. Un-check the "Enable background refresh" box

See link for more details
[This action will cancel a pending refresh data command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278363/this-action-will-cancel-a-pending-refresh-data-command)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35300930)