# Excel Macro will not run from executable

Tags: vba, vb.net, excel, scheduled-tasks

I have written a macro that updates a file daily. I have an .exe file I made in visual basic that will open excel and run the macro. I use task scheduler to run the .exe daily. Here is the .vbs code:

```
Option Explicit On
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        On Error GoTo exitTrying
        Dim exApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        wb = exApp.Workbooks.Open("File_location")
        exApp.Visible = True
        exApp.Run("Macro")
        wb.Close(False)
        exApp.Quit()
exitTrying:
        End
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the macro:

```
Sub Macro()

' Macro
  Application.Run "CopyData"
  Application.Run "PivotRefresh"
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Every time I run my macro from the excel sheet it runs perfectly. However, it will not run at the assigned times in task scheduler. When I run the .exe file I get the following error: " This will cancel a pending data refresh. Continue?" If I continue the macro does not run. This makes me think there is an issue with the .exe file.

The macro copies data into a table and refreshes pivot tables. When the macro is run until the refresh error appears and I press okay a debug error occurs. The debug error shows at the refresh portion of the macro. However, when I look into the excel file that data has not copied. The cells are highlighted where the data should go, but there is no data.

I have tried to enable all macros in the trust center macro settings.

**I have tried unchecking enable background refresh in data connection properties. When the enable background refresh is not checked, the .exe will not open the excel file.**

How can I run the .exe file correctly?

Comment: This seems to be a windows forms application, right? I am not sure if the Form_Load will run when executed via scheduler? Wouldn't a console app be better for this?

Comment: I just tested if Form_Load runs when the exe is called via scheduler. It does!

Comment: The Excel document you are opening *is* an xlsm and not xlsx, right?

Comment: I also did a test with an xl file and a macro inside. It worked fine. So, I guess this is an issue with your xl file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This action will cancel a pending refresh data command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278363/this-action-will-cancel-a-pending-refresh-data-command)

Comment: I tried the solution in "This action will cancel a pending refresh data command ". I have tried unchecking enable background refresh in data connection properties. When the enable background refresh is not checked, the .exe will not open the excel file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The action `Workbooks.Open` has an argument named `[editable]`. Set it to true to see if then your macro runs properly. [Workbooks.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)

Comment: I added the editable argument and the same refresh error appeared. When I unchecked the enable background refresh button, the excel file would not open.